# When TestCafe is ran, Page does not seem to load

Tags: testing, automated-tests, devexpress, e2e-testing, testcafe

Using testcafe, I am trying to open the page https://tribegrouptravel.com. 
When I run the command testcafe chrome test.js it brings up the browser and starts the test, but the page keeps spinning.

Here is the code.

```
    import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
         fixture`Getting Started`.page('https://tribegrouptravel.com')

         const skipTheLines = Selector('div > button').withText('Skip these tips');

         test('Successful Login', async t => {
         // Test code
               await t
              .wait(3000)
              .click(skipTheLines)
              .wait(4000);

      });
```

The page opens in the Chrome browser without testcafe.

Following are the versions

testcafe version: 1.6.1
node.js version: v10.16.3
command-line arguments: "testcafe chrome -e loginTest.js"
browser name and version: Chrome: 78.0.3, Safari: 13.0.3
platform and version: Mac OS X 10.14.6

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  You say "does not seem to load" **and** "the website page opens normally".  What exactly is the problem?  Please describe it in as much detail as possible as well as what steps you have taken to solve the problem.  Context of the problem will help make your question better.

Comment: SO when the test is run, the  page keeps loading, meaning have a spinner. Without using testcafe the page opens correctly in the browser.

@zero298 i updated the description. Hope that helps

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue in Chrome 78.0.3 on Mojave macOS 10.14.5, and TestCafe works for me as expected. See the [screencast](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nabThmvBdnUiGNdKAzX30GM1dthTa67W/view). Please refer to [this](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/faq/#i-have-installed-testcafe-but-i-cannot-run-it-what-should-i-do) section in our documentation for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem
I noticed that by default Testcafe is trying to start test on 10.0.0.2
Changed it to localhost:
`testcafe chrome test1.js  --hostname localhost`
and it solved the problem.